Is it ok to import campaign members to a parent campaign?
Currently, we have a hierarchy with parent and child campaigns. Right now, all campaign members are housed in child campaigns. I have a campaign that isn't relevant to any existing parent campaigns, so I need to create a new one. I'm not sure if it's ok/best practice to import the campaign member list to just a parent campaign or if I should create a child campaign that is essentially the same information that would be contained in the parent campaign. Thanks in advance!

You don't want to duplicate data by having the same members in both parent and child. Aside from that, what's best or not best depends on how the campaigns are used. You should find out by asking your teammates, Marketing folks, etc.

I agree with @identigral - this is very much a question to ask of your business and decide based on your specific use of Campaigns in Salesforce

Thanks for your comment! I wouldn't have campaign members in both. They would either be in a parent campaign that does not have any child campaigns OR they would be in the child campaign.
